# How to remove non market hrs/time on trading view lightweight-chart?

Tags: tradingview-api, lightweight-charts

I'm new to lightweight-chart and have data that 5 minutes apart on each row. Now I need to remove the non market hours - See below. Any option to remove this?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3AQ8.png)

Current chart option

```js
 const chart = createChart(chartContainerRef.current, {
      crosshair: {
        mode: 0, // CrosshairMode.Normal
      },
      layout: {
        background: { type: ColorType.Solid, color: colors.backgroundColor },
        textColor: colors.textColor,
      },
      timeScale: {
        borderColor: "#fff000",
        visible: true,
        timeVisible: true,
        secondsVisible: true,
      },
      width: chartContainerRef.current.clientWidth,
      height: 500,
    });
    chart.timeScale().fitContent();
```

Answer (score 1):

The library will only add a point on the chart for each data point. So if the data isn't there then it won't be plot.

For example:

- If you had data points at: `9:00`, `9:15`, `9:30`, `9:45`.
  then the library would plot `4` points.
- If you remove a point in the middle: `9:00`, `9:30`, `9:45`.
  then the library would only plot `3` points. There won't be a gap left on the time scale for `9:15`.

**TLDR;** Remove the points you don't want to display from the data before providing it to the library via `setData`.